# How to Execute SQL Server query (procedure) from another PC in network

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

### Situation now

We have a netrowk set up. Some PCs have SQL Server 2012 installed, **some don`t**.

Is it possible to write a stored procedure and have it invoked/executed by another user/PC without SQL Server? For example by some .bat/.cmd script, I don`t know.

### Desired situation

1. I write SQL query on my SQL Server management studio.
2. I save the query as a stored procedure. <-- up to here I am OK.
3. I do something that makes the procedure availible to other users. The advice I get from this question (I hope).
4. Other colleagues execute the procedure.
5. They get a result of the query in a CSV.

Answer (score 2):

The client computers that need to run the stored procedure could install the [sqlcmd utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility). This allows for the execution of sql commands on another SQL Server.

```
SQLCmd -S<<SERVERNAME\INSTANCENAME>> -Q "Execute dbo.YourStoredProcedure"
```

And then have your stored procedure save the CSV file to a network drive or send it via e-mail.

Another way to retrieve data could be using the [BCP utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility). In this way the user could connect to your server, execute the query and receive a CSV file to a specified location on their computer.

In both cases it involves installing an additional program on the client computer.

Comment: Thank you for your useful advice.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need SQL Server installed in the client machines to run queries or execute procedures. At most, depending on which programming language you are are using, you need the client installation for SQL Server. This is true for any DBMS, even Microsoft SQL Server 2014.

If you implement you code in Java, for example, you don't need even the MS SQL Server client. The JDBC driver for  MS SQL Server is enough. It can be download from Microsoft and is not part of the SQL Server client installation.